# How to obtain a DB2 Sequence Value in a Multithreaded Application

Tags: sql, multithreading, db2, sequence, identity

I am working on a multithreaded application that uses DB2 for its primary database.  In the past we've mostly used Identity columns for tables where we needed an auto-generated unique identifier.  To do that we would run the below 2 queries in the same transaction:

```
INSERT INTO tbname (IDENTITY_COL, ...) VALUES (DEFAULT, ...);
SELECT IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

We are now being pressured to switch to Sequence instead.  I know you can use "NEXT VALUE FOR *colname*" in both INSERT and SELECT statements, but I can't figure out how to both INSERT and SELECT with the same value without risking a race condition in a multithreaded application.  For example, if I use:

```
INSERT INTO tbname (SEQUENCE_COL, ...) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_COL, ...);
SELECT PREVIOUS VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_COL;
```

Then there's a possibility another INSERT was run between the above INSERT and SELECT, hence providing me the incorrect value.  If I try:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_COL;
```

store the value in a variable and pass that in to the INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO tbname (SEQUENCE_COL, ...) VALUES (variable_value, ...);
```

Then there's a possibility another thread got the same NEXT VALUE and tries to insert the same value, resulting in a DB2 -803 error.  Is it possible to use SEQUENCE columns in a multithreaded environment, or do I need to fight to keep my IDENTITY columns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to what Michael Sharek (correctly) said:

```
INSERT INTO tbname (SEQUENCE_COL, ...) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_COL, ...);
SELECT PREVIOUS VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_COL;
```

Your assumption *Then there's a possibility another INSERT was run between the above INSERT and SELECT, hence providing me the incorrect value*" regarding the above sequence of statements is incorrect.

The "next value" and "previous value" are connection specific.

Access to a sequence from different threads will never create a "race" condition. Each connection has a completely isolated "environment" for the sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the connection-specific clarification.  Exactly what I needed to hear.

Answer (score 6):

You've got a mistaken assumption in your question.

> If I try:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_COL;
```

> store the value in a variable and pass that in to the INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO tbname (SEQUENCE_COL, ...) VALUES (variable_value, ...);
```

> Then there's a possibility another thread got the same NEXT VALUE and tries to insert the same value

That's not correct. The second thread would get a different NEXTVAL and not the same value as the first thread.

I also want to add my opinion on this part:

> We are now being pressured to switch to Sequence instead.

I can't imagine there being a really good reason to switch to sequences from identity. They're basically the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The clarification of connection safety provided by a_horse_with_no_name gives me a better understanding of why it's okay, but both answers helped a lot.  As for the pressure, it's to lose some of the overhead on Identities and give the programmers more rein on how these columns are set (high level explanation).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other correct answers, you can also just use a single statement to insert a row and return inserted values as follows:

```
SELECT SEQUENCE_COL FROM NEW TABLE (
  INSERT INTO tbname (SEQUENCE_COL, ...) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR MY_SEQUENCE, ...)
)
```